# Agrupar registros de un archivo CSV con PHP

Tags: php, array, csv

Buenos días,
Quiero agrupar registros desordenados dentro de un archivo CSV utilizando PHP, he pensado en usar un Arreglo e interar buscando IDs iguales y organizarlos uno debajo del otro, pero podría tener archivos de más de 20 mil registros y no sé que capacidad de almacenamiento tienen los arreglos.

Espero sus comentarios.

Comment: Por experiencia, cuando he trabajado con ficheros csv, un array ha funcionado bien. Incluso con ficheros de más de 100.000 líneas de registros. Lo único que debes de tener en cuenta es ajustar la configuración de memoria del servidor.

Comment: Alguna sugerencia es usar macros para tu excel, que el usuario descargue el formato, lo llene y lo cargue en tu sitio. Desde tu macro podras controlar que el usuario no repita Id's

Comment: Lo que ocurre es que ese archivo Excel es enviado por un proveedor y tendría que ser el proveedor que tenga el archivo... un poco complicado. Lo que si se podría hacer es que el usuario que se encargue de manipular el archivo aquí en la empresa, se encargue de hacer el ordenamiento de forma manual usando Excel. No?

Answer (score 1):

Una de las soluciones más sencilla es que cargues el csv en mysql, utilizando esta sintaxis:

mysql -vvvvv -u  -p -h localhost -e "LOAD DATA INFILE '' INTO TABLE  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ();"

Luego puedes crear una consulta de agrupación y volver a generar el csv de regreso.

El rendimiento en este método es por mucho mejor que hacerlo directamente en php.

Posteriormente para generar el csv, puedes usar:

SELECT 
FROM 
WHERE 
GROUP BY 
ORDER BY 
INTO OUTFILE ''
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ', o ;'
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

Espero te sirva